# Full Calendar not rendering due to lenght of event title fron mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, fullcalendar

I have been playing around with FullCalendar for the past week.

I have identified an issue with the rendering of the calendar in any browser (Edge / Firefox / Chrome) if the title text is longer than 10 characters for the New_Job page, 30 characters for the quote page it does not render, i get a blank white page in the browser, yet if i view the code it looks just fine.

It's incredibly strange why this happens. I have sanitized the mysqlk database table and removed / replaced all special characters such as: # * ( ) ' ` ! - " /r /n

I have a MySQL Database with a table of job_tickets
Each job ticket has a defined job_type of either (New_Job, Quote or Warranty)

1 - I have created the php scripting to query the database table where job_type='Quote' and send the results to the events: [ ] section of the php page quote.php

2 - I have created the php scripting to query the database table where job_type='New_Job' and send the results to the events: [ ] section of the php page new_job.php

3 - I have created the php scripting to query the database table where job_type='Warranty' and send the results to the events: [ ] section of the php page warranty.php

Sample of the code:

```
<?php
    require_once('dist/auth.php');
    $sql = "SELECT id, left(job_address, 10) as title, left(job_details, 10) as description, job_due_date       as start, job_due_date_end as end, color FROM job_tickets where job_type='New_Job'";
    $req = $auth->prepare($sql);
    $req->execute();
    $events = $req->fetchAll();
    ?>
    events: [
    <?php foreach($events as $event): 
    $start = explode(" ", $event['start']);
    $end = explode(" ", $event['end']);
    if($start[1] == '00:00:00'){
    $start = $start[0];
    }else{
    $start = $event['start'];
    }
    if($end[1] == '00:00:00'){
    $end = $end[0];
    }else{
    $end = $event['end'];
    ?>
    {
    id: '<?php echo $event['id']; ?>',
    title: '<?php echo $event['title']; ?>',
    description: '<?php echo $event['description']; ?>',
    start: '<?php echo $start; ?>',
    end: '<?php echo $end; ?>',
    color: '<?php echo $event['color']; ?>',
    },
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    ]
```

it seems to me that there is a limitation of the script to crash and not render in any browser if the title or description text being fed to it is too large.
I'm using XAMPP which is not logging any errors in the apache or php logs

Has anyone else seen this issue?

Comment: I can't see the documentation mention such a limit; and if there was one, you'd rather expect to get a proper error message then. Sure it's not rather about what the title actually _contains_ - like a single quote somewhere in there, messing up your syntax? (You should rather use `json_encode` to get your data into JavaScript here, than writing this out yourself.)

Comment: `i get a blank white page in the browser`...sounds like it's probably a server-side error. Turn on PHP error logging / reporting and ensure the error reporting setting is also switched on for whatever database library you're using (e.g. mysqli and PDO have specific settings you need to enable for them to throw exceptions).

Comment: P.S. As an aside `events: [
    <?php foreach($events as $event): `...etc. This is a terrible, unreadable, unreliable, convoluted way to output the data. Just make a PHP array and then json_encode it. It'll be far easier to understand the code, and far easier to debug it, and creates a much better separation of client- and server-side code. Then after that you can move to using a proper [json event feed](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed) with date filtering, so you're not pointlessly downloading your entire event history every time you load the calendar

Comment: P.P.S. `I have sanitized the mysqlk database table and removed / replaced all special characters such as: # * ( ) ' \` ! - " /r /n` ...it's hard to see why that would make any difference to anything, or indeed what you think is "special" about any of those characters. They're just non-alphanumeric characters that's all. They're all standard ASCII too, not even any UTF-8 issues to consider, from what you've shown. That said, once we have some idea error is making PHP (or perhaps SQL) crash, we'll have more ability to determine what the root cause is.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for your response.

Php Error log showed absolutely nothing, it is set to show all errors.

I found the fault and it's an issue with the Full Calendar script where it will not display the page if there is 1 carriage return in the title and description fields.
I am using fields called job_address and job_details to display the title and description in the calendar event.

I fixed it by running this script across the MySQL table data fields

```sql
UPDATE job_tickets SET job_details = REPLACE(REPLACE(job_details, '\r', ''), '\n', '');
UPDATE job_tickets SET job_address = REPLACE(REPLACE(job_address, '\r', ''), '\n', '');
```

Comment: `it will not display the page if there is 1 carriage return in the title & description fields`...that isn't a fault in fullCalendar...it has no problem with such characters. It's _probably_ related to the crazy way you're rendering the event data (which I mentioned in the comments above).

Comment: Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/LYJeOpO - fullcalendar copes with newline and return characters perfectly fine.